# Unable to Publish ADF Storage Event Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have created storage event trigger in my Azure Data Factory. StorageV2 (general purpose v2) account has been configured with it, If file is place in input container event trigger should run the pipeline. While publishing trigger I got below exception, Unable to publish storeg event trigger.

**The attempt to configure storage notifications for the provided storage account xxxxxxxxxxxxx failed. Please ensure that your storage account meets the requirements described at https://aka.ms/storageevents. The error is Failed to retrieve credentials for request=RequestUri=https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/listAccountSas, Method=POST, response=StatusCode=400, StatusDescription=Bad Request, IsSuccessStatusCode=False, Content=System.Net.HttpWebResponse, responseContent={"error":{"code":"InvalidValuesForRequestParameters","message":"Values for request parameters are invalid: keyToSign."}}**

Answer (score 0):

The same issue observed by other users in the past and the most possible reason for this error could be because of firewall settings. Please check if your storage account have a firewall setup? If yes, please try stopping the firewall and then check if it works.

Also, please double check if your storage type is General purpose V2.

[image]

Comment: Hi UtkarshPal-MT, Thanks for your response, Yes its is working with public endpoint and Enabled blob public access. But as per our security policy we can't enable this option, So do we have any other solution for this issue?

Comment: you can try to deploy Azure IR in managed virtual network. please try https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-data-factory-managed-virtual-network/

Comment: Hi UtkarshPal-MT, I forgot to inform you that we are using SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime.

Answer (score 0):

On your storage account in the networking pane, there is an exception you can enable: "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account."

[Exception that should be enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX40P.png)

In case you do not want to have the public network access enabled from all networks, this setting works with self hosted integration runtimes through adding the virtual network and trusted resource type.